# Best way to load lot of buttons into WrapPanel

Tags: wpf, load, wrappanel

I wonder if it's possible to load ~70 buttons into `WrapPanel` better way that I'm using now.

At this momment it works like:

I have table in DB, columns: `productID`, `productName` (which represent 70 buttons to load, so there is always 70 rows).

Now in loop, using `SqlDataReader` I'm reading:

```
product.price (from table Product), barcode (from table Barcode) where Product.productID = myTableWithButtons.productID
```

If exist then:

using class to create button

```
returnButton(int productID, string picturePath, decimal price)
```

I'm returning button created from `WrapPanel`, 2 textblocks and (if exist) picture inside.
If not exist - insert empty button without any text etc, and set it invisible.

Now tests:
in core2 pc with 4 gb ram - tooks 0,91 sec to load
in D525 processor, 2gb ram - tooks 4-5 sec to load.

Is there any way to load and insert buttons into `WrapPanel` ?
Maybe some `List<buttons>` would be faster?

Every button have style in Resources file - gradient brush, `WrapPanel` with `textBlocks` as content etc.

Thanks for any reply!
Regards

Comment: use `ItemsControl`, change `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` to `WrapPanel`, fill `DataTable` with your SQL and bind it to `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`, add template and WPF will create all buttons for you

Comment: @dkozl beat me to it. That is exactly the way to do it.

Comment: Fast and easy explain answer. thanks, ill check that :)

Comment: By the way - I need to do something just like You said but with static Listview. In that way i need to wrte all ItemTemplate in codebehind. Can you help with any example?

Comment: @user13657 why create control in code behind and what do you mean by static? why not in XAML? what do you want to achieve?